# CSS - Width of Slider in Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox

I am fixing a site. And I encountered a problem with the slider I used. The slider I used is orbit slider.

Here's the thing:

Each slide loads 1 pixel less than the container width then stretched after a second and maximize its container's width.

I tried width:100% in each div inside the parent container but the css rule does not fix my problem.

All modern browsers looks great already except firefox.

The site is http://www.shamarra.co.nz/test/

**Q:How to fill the width at the initial state of each slide so that it will meet the standard slider output in FIREFOX.**

I suspected that the slider needs a css modification to fix this.

[image]

Comment: firefox looks fine for me, are you sure there is an issue?

Comment: @Evan: yes, look at the edge of the slider in the right. There's is a small gap(padding or something) that resizes immediately after a second. Don't zoom in the view. Then you can notice the error.

Comment: I think the problem may have to do with the fact that the opacity of each image is *starting* at `1` and then being brought down to `0` only to be brought back up to `1` again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with FireFox 10+. There have been multiple bug reports for it.

Report 1:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745549

Report 2:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=780521

I'm not sure there is a fix yet, last I read they haven't found one for this bug.

Comment: Thank you very much evean I solved the problem when I read the report 1. The solution is by using box-shadow in each images of the slide.

Comment: @jed Excellent, happy to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

***Just Try With The Following :***

On your css file : http://www.shamarra.co.nz/wp-content/plugins/wp-orbit-slider/css/default.css

Remove / Hide Following lines and refresh / clear your browser cache in firefox.

```
#orbit-inside img.orbit-slide {
    /*height: auto;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;*/
}
```

Also,

```
    div.orbit > img {
        /*left: 0;*/
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }

    div.orbit > img, div.orbit > a {
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
        /*left: 0;*/
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        /*width: 100%;*/
    }
```

Then it will start working perfectly. I have tested in my local server it was working fine.

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.